# Clique constante usando Selenium não funciona

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

**Objetivo:** Clicar 4 vezes no mesmo botão "Ver Mais"

**Problema:** O comando de clique funciona nas 2 primeiras vezes, após isso, ele não funciona mais e retorna `TimeoutException`

Código:

```
ops = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
ops.add_argument("start-maximized")
ops.add_argument('disable-infobars')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=ops, executable_path='C:\\Users\\danie\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://busca.estadao.com.br/?tipo_conteudo=Not%C3%ADcias&quando=01%2F08%2F2018-01%2F11%2F2018&q=Jo%C3%A3o%20D%C3%B3ria')

for i in range(4):
    try:
        #"btn-mais" é a classe do botão que quero clicar
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn-mais'))))
        time.sleep(5)
    except:
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que quando clicas em "carregar mais" a página faz um pedido ajax e junta a resposta do servidor à `div` principal, e o botão em que clicaste inicialmente fica escondido e o driver não o consegue encontrar (por isso é que recebes o `TimeoutException`.

Alterando a forma como pesquisas pelo botão a clicar resolve o problema:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",\
WebDriverWait(driver,20).\
until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".mais-itens:last-child > div > a"))))
```